# Output showing too early

Tags: bash, printf, echo

I made a small Bash-script to make my life easier. But I encountered a problem which I can't fix.

**What I want**
I've made a small script which will check for php-errors in a file each time that file gets saved/changed. This is done without me needing to run a command each time. So I run the Bash-script once on my second screen, and than each time when I save my PHP-file on screen one; I get the eventual errors shown on screen two automatically.

**Basic algorithm**

1. Get the hash of the file
2. Compare it to it's previous hash
3. If it differs, the file is changed/saved: Check if there are errors using the `php -l` command
4. Print out the result from `php -l`

**Problem:**
The result from `php -l` gets printed out before my code asked for it.

**Code**

```
#!/bin/bash

#Declaring basic variables here
fileToCheck="$1"

oldHash=("")
checksum=("")

#Function to get a striped line as long as the terminal width
function lineAmount {
    cwidth=`tput cols`
    lines=""
    for i in $(seq $(expr $cwidth - 33)); do lines="$lines-";done
    echo $lines
}


#Function to show the actual error
function showError {
    msg=$1
    time=`date +"%c"`
    l=$(lineAmount)

    if [ "$msg" == "No" ]
        then
            msg="No errors detected."
    fi

    printf "\n\n$time $l \n$msg\n"
}

#Start-screen------------------------------------------------
printf "Starting session for $1 at $time \n$(lineAmount)\n"
if [ ! -f $1 ]
    then
        echo "[Error] File $1 not found."
        exit
fi
printf "\n\n\n"
#------------------------------------------

#Printing out error when file changed
while true
    do
        sleep 0.6 
        checksum=($(sha256sum $fileToCheck))
        checksum=${checksum[0]}

        if [ "$checksum" != "$oldHash" ]
            then
                error=$(php -l $fileToCheck)
                oldHash=$checksum

                showError $error
        fi
done
```

**Test file (test.php):**

```
<?php
    function foo() {

    }
?>
```

**Output of script:**

```
Starting session for /home/name/Desktop/test.php at  
-----------------------------------------------





Thu 11 Aug 2016 08:16:15 PM CEST ----------------------------------------------- 
No errors detected.
```

Now, in *test.php* I delete line 4:

```
<?php
    function foo() {


?>
```

This will of course give an error, and my script shows that error:

```
Starting session for /home/name/Desktop/test.php at  
-----------------------------------------------





Thu 11 Aug 2016 08:16:15 PM CEST ----------------------------------------------- 
No errors detected.
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file in /home/name/Desktop/test.php on line 6


Thu 11 Aug 2016 08:19:37 PM CEST ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Parse
```

But like you can see, this is not a nice output.
`PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file in /home/name/Desktop/test.php on line 6` should be printed below the second dotted line. Not below "No errors found." (The first output).

**Expected output:**

```
Starting session for /home/name/Desktop/test.php at  
-----------------------------------------------





Thu 11 Aug 2016 08:16:15 PM CEST ----------------------------------------------- 
No errors detected.


Thu 11 Aug 2016 08:19:37 PM CEST ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file in /home/name/Desktop/test.php on line 6
```

I tried a lot, I tried to change my algorithm a bit, searched up a lot; but it ain't working.
I guess the problem is somewhere on line 51, or 29. But I really can't see what's wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: How are you editing the php file?  Is your editor auto-saving for you perhaps?

Comment: @EricRenouf I'm using Vim, and I'm saving with the :w function. No auto-save function as far as I know. I also tried it with the default Text Editor on Linux Mint and got the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a stripped down and simplified version of your problem:

> Why does this print an error message immediately instead of assigning it to the variable?

```
$ error=$(php -l test.php)
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file in test.php on line 5
```

---

`php -l` prints error messages to stderr like a good Unix citizen should. `$(..)` only captures stdout.

If you want to capture stdout and stderr together, you can use:

```
error=$(php -l $fileToCheck 2>&1)
```

You should also quote your variables so that the message is passed as a single parameter, since you're currently throwing away most of it ([shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) is helpful):

```
showError "$error"
```

Being a good citizen, `php` also returns a useful exit code, so instead of trying to match a "No" to see if it's successful, you can just check the status directly:

```
if error=$(php -l $fileToCheck 2>&1)
then
  echo "No problems"
else
  echo "It failed with these messages: $error"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and tips! It's working perfectly now. However, could you explain the `2>&1` part a bit more please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-shell-what-does-21-mean